# RecyclerView lagging more than GridViewAdapter when adding images

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

EDITED: Didn't realize my GridViewAdapter extended ArrayAdapter

I have a RecyclerView and I'm adding images into the ArrayList, and calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` when I'm done. It lags by a tiny bit when I scroll while the images are being added asynchronously.

I have a "GridViewAdapter" extending an ArrayAdapter and I'm adding images into the ArrayList as well, and then calling `ArrayAdapter.add()` on the image holder directly. It doesn't lag when the images are being added asynchronously.

EDIT 2: My RecyclerView implementation is actually using `set` on a pre-existing position in the arraylist (and replacing old data).
My GridVIew implementation is using `add` on the arraylist (and adding completely new data). I just looked up the big o complexity of the arraylist -- it is O(1) for adding and O(n) for searching (to replace item). Would this have anything to do with the lag?

How do I make it so that the RecyclerView would not lag by that tiny bit?

Comment: please show your recycler view code. It might not be an issue with images itself.

Comment: What is GridViewAdapter.add()?  That's not a platform or compat lib component.

Comment: Please post your RecyclerView's Adapter code here

Comment: Woops @DougStevenson I realized it was a custom class extending ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about decreasing the size of items? As in not loading all items but just a subset. Load 10 -> user reaches the bottom -> Load 10 more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your OnBindViewHolder method.

```
boolean flag = false;
//Get url of the photo  saved in model
 String src = list.get(position).ImageUrl;  
//Get the tag associated with it
 String newSrc = (String) holder.ivPlayerImage.getTag();
 // if both equal set flag true    
 if(newSrc.equals(src)){
                flag  =true;
            }
            else{
                flag = false;
            }
// if flag not true, meaning image url has changed for particular entry , and so u load again otherwise no need to load again(This will reduce flickering)
   if(!flag) {
            //load imageurl in the imageview
            holder.ivPlayerImage.setTag(src);
        }
```

Hope it helps